# Lost connection to MySQL server during query when creating index

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am creating a fulltext index on a large table (using command line), so I expect it to take a very long time. Unfortunately every time I get this error after some time (about 1 hour):

```
mysql> CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ix_fulltext_catalog ON catalog(catalog_content);
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Then when I try to run any command, it just reconnects:

```
mysql> show variables like 'connect_timeout';
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    8
```

I tried to set many variables to higher values, but it didn't help. These are my values:

```
| Variable_name                                 | Value              |
+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| connect_timeout                               | 172800             |
| disconnect_on_expired_password                | ON                 |
| init_connect                                  |                    |
| max_connect_errors                            | 100                |
| max_connections                               | 151                |
| max_user_connections                          | 0                  |
| mysqlx_connect_timeout                        | 30                 |
| mysqlx_max_connections                        | 100                |
| performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size | 512                |
| connect_timeout                               | 172800             |
| delayed_insert_timeout                        | 300                |
| have_statement_timeout                        | YES                |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout                   | 1                  |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                      | 50                 |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout                    | OFF                |
| interactive_timeout                           | 172800             |
| lock_wait_timeout                             | 31536000           |
| mysqlx_connect_timeout                        | 30                 |
| mysqlx_idle_worker_thread_timeout             | 60                 |
| mysqlx_interactive_timeout                    | 28800              |
| mysqlx_port_open_timeout                      | 0                  |
| mysqlx_read_timeout                           | 30                 |
| mysqlx_wait_timeout                           | 28800              |
| mysqlx_write_timeout                          | 60                 |
| net_read_timeout                              | 30                 |
| net_write_timeout                             | 60                 |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout                        | 31536000           |
| slave_net_timeout                             | 60                 |
| wait_timeout                                  | 172800             |
+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

I also checked the `error.log` file, but there are no errors at all! It seems like the server just 'falls asleep' after 1 hour, like if nothing was happening in the background. Can somebody help please?

**EDIT:** as @danblack suggested, I tried to use `dmesg` and it shows I'm running out of memory.

```
Out of memory: Killed process 489295 (mysqld) total-vm:12674556kB, anon-rss:10791368kB, 
file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:126 pgtables:21724kB oom_score_adj:0
```

Comment: Are you sure about the error log? Did mysql on the server restart? Check server `dmesg`, it might have OOM in which case there would be nothing in the log except for the server restart after your connection failure.

Comment: Check your server's error log.

Comment: I checked dmesg and this is what I see:
Out of memory: Killed process 487644 (mysqld) total-vm:12773876kB, anon-rss:10806008kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:126 pgtables:21616kB oom_score_adj:0
Is this because my memory is too low for such a large table/index?

Comment: You probably don't have enough ram. Technically MySQL is configured for more ram than is really available, however if it takes an 1hour before crashing that seems like it should be quicker, even on something described as a catalog.

Comment: I have 16 GB of RAM. But my catalog is 50 GB and contains a lot of text to be indexed into a fulltext index. So is there any other config I can try? Or is there no choice but to increase RAM if I want to build that index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to OOM:

option 1:

Reduce `innodb_buffer_pool_size` (online) during the adding the index.

option 2:

Use another full text search implementation and not MySQL. Dedicated applications like Solr, Sphinx-search etc for text search do intuitive search a lot better.

(disclaimer I've only used versions earlier than MySQL-8.0).

Comment: Reducing `innodb_buffer_pool_size` worked, I changed it to 8M and my index created successfully after 6 hours :) thanks!